# Install Git automatically from sources inside Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

Is it possible to configure Git installation inside Jenkins, using "Global tool configuration" > "Git" > "Install automatically"?

The case is:

- I've Jenkins 2 installed on Debian 7 server,
- latest Git in package repository for Debian 7 is 1.9.1 - https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/git
- I need some functionalities add in Git 2.x.

Yes, I can install it from sources in system, but it would require additional managing in future to update it etc. Changing version inside Jenkins would be much clearer.

I've tried that configuration:
[image: Jenkins git installer config]

but after I set that as "Git executable" in project conf on run I get:

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Test_GIT/workspace
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:663)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:464)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1042)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1082)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command:  init /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Test_GIT/workspace
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1759)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1725)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1721)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1391)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:661)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Test_GIT/workspace"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:243)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:212)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:815)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1748)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 21 more
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: no.............